# How to implement "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" for all models in a MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges can be applied to all models in the Application_Start of Global.asax instead of using it for each model like this.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MovieDBContext>(new MovieInitializer());
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Initializer is context-wide, and this concrete initializer is applied when ANY model in whole context is changed. What you mean applying initializer to all models?

Comment: I am new to Code First.  May be the actual question is can I use same Dbcontext for ALL models?  If so, how?

Comment: You should use same context for ALL related models. Maybe [this vide](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Chris-Zavaleta-Entity-Framework-Code-First-Domain-Driven-CRUD) will give you basic knowledge about code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you have multiple types context accessing the same database the "trick" is to create one special context which will include all your models and use it only for database initialization.

Comment: Most of the time all of the models in a project access same database.  The tutorial I was following for a MVC4 project was not clear.